# SuppressWarnings: Can use functional operations

Tags: java, netbeans

How do I use `@SuppressWarnings` to hide this warning whenever I use normal `for` loops instead of functional operations in Java 8?

Comment: This cannot be suppresed using `@SupressWarnings` because it's an IDE warning.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: I guess that's the answer then

Comment: I don't post it as an answer because I don't know how to disable it. I don't use NetBeans.

Comment: You can click the error symbol on the side and click "disable this error" or something like that.

Answer (score 6):

I found what appears to be the correct option:

1. Select from Menu Tools -> Options
2. Select Editor Button at the Top
3. Select Hints Tab
4. Select Language Java in Combo Box
5. In the tree expand General and uncheck "Use functional operations"